# .htaccess redirect subdomain to primary domain if desktop, excluding certain folders

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have `domain.com`.

I also have `m.domain.com`.

If I try to access `m.domain.com` from a desktop, I want to redirect the user to `domain.com` UNLESS the user is explicitly trying to access a specific folder (in my case: `wp-admin` for login to wordpress).

Part of my .htaccess has the following code which properly detects and handles the redirect but I am stuck on the folder exclusion portion.

```
#Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
#insert folder exclusion 
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(MSIE.*Windows\ NT|Lynx|Safari|Opera|Firefox|Konqueror) [NC]
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(^.*(Opera\ Mini|SymbianOS|Mobile)) [NC]
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(\w+)\.domain\.com [NC]
#RewriteRule .* http://domain.com/ [R,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to redirect when the root is accessed, then perhaps you could add the following before the last line with the RewriteRule.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
```

This will then only process the redirect if you accessed http://m.domain.com/ directly.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(wp-admin|etc|etc)$
```

The above will redirect only if the folder being access is not in the list (wp-admin, etc, etc).

Comment: Well, it's not exactly what I was looking for but works just fine. Thanks!

Comment: Just re-read the question, and see what you meant.
I've edited my answer now, is this more what you were looking for?

Comment: Oh there we go, yes, perfect :) Thanks again!